# Iterating over list with lambda forEach Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I have a list of 30 random numbers that correspond to 1 of 8 colours, and I need to iterate over the 8 colors(or 30 numbers) and find the number of times each colour occurs. I need to do this using lambdas and functional programming, so no traditional for loops.

```
val iterator = colours.toList().iterator()

iterator.forEach{

    println("$it count: " + (numbers
            .map{a -> colours[a]}
            .count{it == ("$it")}))
}
```

The problem currently is my output for count is just 50, not the specific number of times a colour occurs.

If I do it like this:

```
println("Red count:" +    (numbers
        .map{a -> colours[a]}
        .count{it ==  ("red")}))
```

it outputs the correct number, but not with the loop.

What it ouputs:

```
green count: 50 

red count: 50
```

what it should output (for example)

```
green count:9

red count:3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a named parameter to your forEach loop. The implicit name "it" is getting shadowed by the count function.

```
val iterator = colours.toList().iterator()

iterator.forEach { colour ->

    println("$colour count: " + (numbers
        .map{a -> colours[a]}
        .count{it == ("$colour")}))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do a nested iteration here. Currently you're operating at O(n^2) since you have to traverse the list once for every element. Since you know you're working with a small number of potential values, you could instead just group them by value and then map the values to the size of the resulting lists, i.e.

```
val colourNames = listOf("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "indigo", "violet", "black")

// Generates 30 random numbers between 0 and 8 (exclusive)
val randomColours = (0 until 30).map { (0 until colourNames.size).random() }

val result = randomColours
  .groupBy { color -> colourNames[color] } // outputs a Map<String, List<Int>>
  .mapValues { (color, colorCountList) -> colorCountList.size } // Map<String, Int>

println(result) // {yellow=4, orange=4, red=5, indigo=3, blue=8, green=2, violet=2, black=2}
```